# Use of user input date in a calculated field

Tags: ms-access

I'm trying to count how many records, in a query, have a date equal or superior to the one entered by end user, in a text box on that same form.
The query field to test is [ABERTO EM] and the text box with a user date is [tbDesde].

This formula doesn't work:

```
=Count(IIf([ABERTO EM]>[tbDesde];1;Null))
```

This one, with fixed date, works:

```
=Count(IIf([ABERTO EM]>#01-07-2016#;1;Null))
```

Changing it to "=[tbDesde]" I get the value in [tbDesde]; the same with "=DateValue([tbDesde])" (the first seems to return text,with left alignment, the second a date with right alignment).

Can someone help me on this?

Comment: add PARAMETERS  [tbDesde] DateTime; before the query

Comment: Assuming this is a parameter, Access will use it as a variant data type unless explicitly told otherwise. =[tbDesde] would return exactly the input given by the user but would still be a variant type. If the user inputted '1/1/16', Access doesn't know if that's a string or a date. By declaring the parameter as type `DateTime` as @nazark states, you are explicitly telling Access to treat the input as a date data type instead of a variant, which should fix your formula.

Comment: NOTE: you say you're testing that the date is 'equal or superior to', but you are only testing 'superior to'. Should be `=Count(IIf([ABERTO EM]>=[tbDesde];1;Null))` if you want to test 'greater than or equal to'.

Comment: I'm not english natural, not an Access expert (by any means!), I guess I didn't explain myself correctly.
My query does not depend on this input box. I'm trying to get counts from records on that query, based on an form input field by the user (_tbDesde_ text box).
1. Why `=Count(IIf([ABERTO EM]>=DateValue([tbDesde]);1;Null))` doesn't work neither? Shouldn't DateValue return a date from a string?
2. Is this the correct way of doing things or should I take another route?

Comment: Textbox works for me without conversion. Cannot replicate issue.